# Problem with duplicate functionality on meta

Tags: discussion, bug

I was on meta and so a post was flagged as a possible duplicate.  When I went to the duplicate I found there was no answer.  I thought that was strange as the text for the duplicate close reason is:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

By that reason we should not be able to pick a post that doesn't have an answer for a possible duplicate.  I tired this on SO and I got:

[image]

Which is what I expected.  When I tested it here I got:

[image]

Is there a reason the duplicate flagging works different on Meta then on SO?

Comment: Your proposed Meta duplicate target has a deleted answer. Maybe that's a factor? Maybe not.

Comment: It is a shame the question this is a duplicate of has an answer.